# How to add a header in HTTP request c#?

Tags: c#, http

I need to send a request and to authenticate i need to add a header. I'm new to all this and probably its a stupid question but please i really need this. I tried to use `HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();` but theres an error.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); // <- error

var request = httpClient.GetAsync("link").Result;

Console.ReadKey();
```

The error is `Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface`

Comment: Could you share a minimal code fragment? There are several different HTTP client implementations in .NET

Comment: Its not a bad idea to do a simple google search, before posting on stack overflow. Anyway all you need is to replace HttpHeaders line with  the kind of code below(this one adds an apikey)

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", key);

Answer (score 1):

I give you an example. I make a request to get access token and then add `Authorization` to the header.

To request the access token:

```
 var tokenClient = new User()
 {
    username= "admin",
    password= "@dmin",
  };

  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<string>("https://api.example.com/api/v1/token", tokenClient);

  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
      return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

  }
```

Then to add `Authorization` to the header, add the following code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
```